# Create new custom payment module

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to create a new custom payment module in Magento 1.9, just like cash-on-delivery. anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/llapgoch/magento-custom-payment-method

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/28/magento-create-custom-payment-method/

you can follow this, it will be helpful for you to create custom payment method